# Differentiable function $f'\left( x \right) - 2f\left( x \right) > 0$

Tags: calculus

If $f: ℝ → ℝ $ is a differentiable function such that $f'\left( x \right) - 2f\left( x \right) > 0$ for all $x ∈ ℝ$, and $f(0) = 1$, then

[A] $f(x)$ is increasing in $(0, ∞)$

[B] $f(x)$ is decreasing in $(0, ∞)$

[C] $f(x)>e^{2x}$ in $(0, ∞)$

[D] $f'(x)<e^{2x}$ in $(0, ∞)$

The official answer is [A] and [C]

My approach is as follow

$f'\left( x \right) - 2f\left( x \right) > 0$

$\frac{d}{{dx}}\left( {f\left( x \right){e^{ - 2x}}} \right) > 0$

$t(x) = f\left( x \right){e^{ - 2x}}$

For $x\in(0,\infty)$

$t(x) = f\left( x \right){e^{ - 2x}}>t(0)$

$t(0)=1$ as $f(0)=1$ & $e^{-2*0}=1$

Hence for $x\in(0,\infty)$ , $f\left( x \right)>{e^{  2x}}$, hence $[C]$

As $e^{-2x}>0$

And $t(x)$ is increasing function therefore $f(x)$ is increasing for $x\in(0,\infty)$ , hence [A]

How do we satisfy **option [D]** is incorrect

Comment: You said the answer is [A] and [C]. Why are you trying to prove [D]?

Comment: I need to show why D is not the correct answer

Comment: Option B is incorrect because option A is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $f'(x) > 2f(x) > 2e^{2x}$ for every $x \in (0,\infty)$ which is incompatible with $f'(x) < e^{2x}$ for *any* $x \in (0,\infty)$.